# How to improve query (avoid too many JOINs)

Tags: sql

I want to see if there is a way to replace or improve the query that I have,
This query is joining several tables, I have been looking around and it looks that the best way to improve this is reducing the number of JOINs that I have, but I dont really know how to, should I made a table a part for each JOIN?

```
INNER JOIN tContract CN On CU.CustomerID = CN.CustomerID
INNER JOIN tContractProgram CP On CN.ContractID = CP.ContractID
INNER JOIN tOperationalProgram OP on OP.ContractProgramID = cp.ContractProgramID
INNER JOIN tPackage P On OP.PackageID = P.PackageID
INNER JOIN tJobs J On P.PackageID = J.PackageID
LEFT JOIN AM6_TASK t on j.JobAssessID = t.JobAssessID
LEFT JOIN vTransgrid_LIDAR TL ON TL.JobAssessID = J.JobAssessID
LEFT JOIN Active.dbo.EXT_TASK_TRANSGRID_EVW TT ON TT.TaskID = J.JobID

LEFT JOIN 
(   SELECT LV.Code, LV.[Description]
    FROM [Active].[dbo].[LOOKUP_EVW] as L
    LEFT JOIN [Active].[dbo].[LOOKUPVALUE_EVW] as LV on L.[LookupID] = LV.[LookupId]
    WHERE L.Name  = 'List_NoticeMethod'

) as LVFN ON LVFN.Code = TT.FieldNotification

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT SOR.JobAssessID, SOR.BOMDate, 
        SOR.SORItemCode_Short, SOR.SORItemCode, SOR.LineTotal, SOR.SORItemQty
        ,ACT.ActivityType, ACT.Action
    FROM tCustomer CU
    INNER JOIN tContract CN On CU.CustomerID = CN.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN tContractProgram CP On CN.ContractID = CP.ContractID
    INNER JOIN tOperationalProgram OP on OP.ContractProgramID = cp.ContractProgramID
    INNER JOIN tPackage P On OP.PackageID = P.PackageID
    INNER JOIN tJobs J On P.PackageID = J.PackageID
    INNER JOIN tActivity ACT On ACT.JobAssessID = J.JobAssessID
    INNER JOIN AM6_SORITEM SOR On SOR.SourceID= ACT.ActivityID AND SOR.JobID = ACT.JobID AND SOR.JobAssessID = ACT.JobAssessID 
    WHERE CU.Customer = 'TRANSGRID' 
    AND ProgramName = 'Lidar Works 21-22 FY' 
    AND ACT.ActivityType in ('Assessment', 'Update') 
    AND SOR.LineTotal <> 0) ASMT On J.JobAssessID = ASMT.JobAssessID 

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT SOR.JobAssessID, SOR.BOMDate, ACT.Action, ACT.Status,
        SOR.SORItemCode_Short, SOR.SORItemCode, SOR.LineTotal, SOR.SORItemQty
    FROM tCustomer CU
    INNER JOIN tContract CN On CU.CustomerID = CN.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN tContractProgram CP On CN.ContractID = CP.ContractID
    INNER JOIN tOperationalProgram OP on OP.ContractProgramID = cp.ContractProgramID
    INNER JOIN tPackage P On OP.PackageID = P.PackageID
    INNER JOIN tJobs J On P.PackageID = J.PackageID
    INNER JOIN tActivity ACT On ACT.JobAssessID = J.JobAssessID
    INNER JOIN AM6_SORITEM SOR On SOR.SourceID= ACT.ActivityID 
    AND SOR.JobID = ACT.JobID AND SOR.JobAssessID = ACT.JobAssessID 
    WHERE CU.Customer = 'TRANSGRID'
    AND ProgramName = 'Lidar Works 21-22 FY'
    AND ACT.ActivityType in ('Cutting') 
    AND ACT.Status = 'Complete'
    AND SOR.LineTotal <> 0
) Cut On J.JobAssessID = Cut.JobAssessID AND Cut.SORItemCode = ASMT.SORItemCode
```

I will look forward for any suggestion
Have a good day

Comment: Hi - I don't know what this means "should I made a table a part for each JOIN". However, if you need data from all those tables then you need to join to (or possibly sub-select from) those tables. If you reuse some of those subselects elsewhere then you could create them as views to make your SQL easier to write/understand - but that won't affect performance. If your query is slow then look at the EXPLAIN PLAN and see where it is slow and then make sure all your tables are indexed appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I've had success in a similar situation by introducing temporary tables (or CTEs). E.g., look at

```
SELECT SOR.JobAssessID, SOR.BOMDate, 
    SOR.SORItemCode_Short, SOR.SORItemCode, SOR.LineTotal, SOR.SORItemQty
    ,ACT.ActivityType, ACT.Action, ACT.Status
FROM tCustomer CU
INNER JOIN tContract CN On CU.CustomerID = CN.CustomerID
INNER JOIN tContractProgram CP On CN.ContractID = CP.ContractID
INNER JOIN tOperationalProgram OP on OP.ContractProgramID = cp.ContractProgramID
INNER JOIN tPackage P On OP.PackageID = P.PackageID
INNER JOIN tJobs J On P.PackageID = J.PackageID
INNER JOIN tActivity ACT On ACT.JobAssessID = J.JobAssessID
INNER JOIN AM6_SORITEM SOR On SOR.SourceID= ACT.ActivityID 
AND SOR.JobID = ACT.JobID AND SOR.JobAssessID = ACT.JobAssessID 
WHERE CU.Customer = 'TRANSGRID' 
AND ProgramName = 'Lidar Works 21-22 FY' 
AND ACT.ActivityType in ('Assessment', 'Update') 
AND SOR.LineTotal <> 0
```

If that was inserted into a temporary table you could simplify the end part to

```
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT SOR.JobAssessID, SOR.BOMDate, 
        SOR.SORItemCode_Short, SOR.SORItemCode, SOR.LineTotal, SOR.SORItemQty
        ,ACT.ActivityType, ACT.Action
    FROM #temp
    WHERE ACT.ActivityType in ('Assessment', 'Update') 
) ASMT On J.JobAssessID = ASMT.JobAssessID 

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT SOR.JobAssessID, SOR.BOMDate, ACT.Action, ACT.Status,
        SOR.SORItemCode_Short, SOR.SORItemCode, SOR.LineTotal, SOR.SORItemQty
    FROM #temp
    WHERE ACT.ActivityType in ('Cutting') 
    AND ACT.Status = 'Complete'

) Cut On J.JobAssessID = Cut.JobAssessID AND Cut.SORItemCode = ASMT.SORItemCode
```

But importantly, you could add an index to the temporary file on `JobAssessID` and `SORItemCode` to improve performance.

You are using the same combination of tables several times - that screams "set up a View" as suggested NickW, which can also be indexed see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver16